# How to create a useEffect that only updates when firestore updates?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

First off, let me say that I probably worded my question terribly... sorry.

I currently have a useEffect in my application that when you load my page it takes the data from my Firestore collection and sets it to an array to map on screen with a component. It works perfectly fine, however after about 10 minutes of running my application I receive the error "**@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.15.0): Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Quota exceeded.**".

I added a console log and it looks like this is because my useEffect is constantly trying to read the data from the collection in firestore.

My question is, **is there a way to only make this useEffect update the data / run when a new collection is added or deleted / modified?**

**Code:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import '../index.css';
import './Home.css';
import Note from '../components/Note';
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext';
import { db } from '../firebase';
import { ReactComponent as Add } from '../imgs/add.svg';
import { doc, onSnapshot, query, collection } from 'firebase/firestore';

function Home() {
    // Firebase states
    const { currentUser } = useAuth();
    const noteboardCollectionRef = collection(db, `users/${currentUser.uid}/noteboard-app`);
    // useStates
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

    //useEffect
    useEffect(()=>{
        const q = query(noteboardCollectionRef)
        const noteboardFirebase = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot)=>{
            let noteArr = []
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
                noteArr.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
            });
            setNotes(noteArr);
            console.log(notes)
        })
        return noteboardFirebase;
    })
    // Start of all functions
    
  return (
    <>
    <div className='home-container'>
        <div className='home-header flex'>
            <h1 className='font-carter-one'>Noteboard</h1>
            <div className='home-header-dark-container'>
                <label className='font-carter-one'>Dark Mode</label>
               <span className='home-header-dark-mode'>
                    <input type='checkbox' checked/>
                    <span className='dark-mode-slider pointer'/>
                </span> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className='home-body flex-center-all'>
            <div className='home-new-note flex-center-all flex-column pointer' onClick={()=>{setAddNoteModal(true)}}>
                <Add className='pointer' id='new-note'/>
                <h2 className='font-carter-one'>Add Note</h2>
            </div>
            {notes.map(((note, index) => <Note key={index} note={note} />))}
        </div>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: UseEffect only updates when the values in the bottom brackets changes, so have a value that changes on firebase value change and it will refresh the UseEffect `UseEffect(()=>{}, [value]` Remember to read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) before asking questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this error because you dont have dependencies in the useEffect i.e

```
useEffect(()=>{...
       },[])  // You are missing this []
```

Because of which the useEffect runs every time the page is rendered , which is causing to make unlimited requests to the server which is leading to `quota exceeded error` in firebase

- If array is null i.e `[]` then it runs only the first time the page is rendered.
- If you want the useEffect to run only when the firestore is changed add dependency of `notes` i.e `[notes]`.

Now `useEffect` will run only when there is change in `notes` !!

Your final code should look like:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        const q = query(noteboardCollectionRef)
        const noteboardFirebase = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot)=>{
            let noteArr = []
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
                noteArr.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
            });
            setNotes(noteArr);
            console.log(notes)
        })
        return noteboardFirebase;
    }[notes])                // <-- add dependency of notes
```

Answer (score 1):

Add dependency to [] like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{

  doSomething()

},[dependency])
```

when dependency is changed, doSomething() will run again.

You can see detail in [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)!

So, as for your question you should edit code to this:

```
    //useEffect
    useEffect(()=>{
        const q = query(noteboardCollectionRef)
        const noteboardFirebase = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot)=>{
            let noteArr = []
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
                noteArr.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
            });
            setNotes(noteArr);
            console.log(notes)
        })
        return noteboardFirebase;
    },[notes])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use onSnapshot() to make this happen something like this ;

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { firestore } from './firebase';

function MyComponent() {
  const [document, setDocument] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = firestore
  .doc('my-collection/my-document')
  .onSnapshot((doc) => {
    setDocument(doc.data());
  });

return () => {
  unsubscribe();
 };
  }, []);

return (
<div>
  {document ? (
    <div>
      <h1>{document.title}</h1>
      <p>{document.body}</p>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <p>Loading...</p>
  )}
</div>
);
}
```